# jQuery multiple hover events- mouseleave not firing

Tags: jquery, hover, fadeout, mouseleave

**Action:** hover across multiple "h2" elements in one sweep of the mouse.

**Expected behavior:** fadeIn and fadeOut corresponding "article" elements, one by one. Only one article should be visible at a time, and no article elements should be visible after mouseleave all h2 elements.

**Actual behavior:** one or more articles are visible.

**My response:** ??? Try things for 2 days... ??? Go to stackoverflow and hope for help. (Thanks in advance!)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0n0g0gtx/)

```
<div>
    <h2>heading 1</h2>
    <h2>heading 2</h2>
    <h2>heading 3</h2>
</div>
<div>
    <article>article 1</article>
    <article>article 2</article>
    <article>article 3</article>
</div>

<style>
    article {
        display: none;
    };
</style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

var clicked = false;
var hovered = false;
//click behavior    
    $("h2").click(function(event){
        var index = $(this).closest("h2").index() + 1;
        $("article:not(article:nth-of-type(" + index + "))").fadeOut();
           $("article").promise().done(function(){
               if (clicked == true) {
                   $("article:nth-of-type(" + index + ")").fadeOut();
                   clicked = false;
                   hovered = false;
               } else if (hovered == true){
                    clicked = true;
               } else {
                   $("article:nth-of-type(" + index + ")").fadeIn();
                   clicked = true;
               }

        });
    });

 //click anywhere else to hide articles     
    $(document).click(function(event){
        if (!$(event.target).closest("h2").length) {            
            $("article").fadeOut();
            clicked = false;
            hovered = false;
        };
    });
//hover behavior

    $("h2").hover(function(event){
        var index = $(this).closest("h2").index() + 1;
        if (clicked == false) {
            hovered = true;
            $("article").promise().done(function(){
                $("article:not(article:nth-of-type(" + index + "))").fadeOut();
                $("article").promise().done(function(){
                    $("article:nth-of-type(" + index + ")").fadeIn();
            });});
        };}, function() {
        if (clicked == false) {
            $("article").promise().done(function(){
                $("article").fadeOut();
                hovered = false;
            });
        }; 
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0n0g0gtx/4/

You need to "finish" the animation first and your code is very messy. I have simplified the code to be like this:

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on({
        mouseenter: function () {            
            $("article").finish();   
            $("article").eq($(this).index()).fadeIn();
        },

        mouseleave: function () {            
            $("article").fadeOut();
        }
    }, "h2");
});
```

This code works by "finishing" all animations on article and then fades in the article based on the h2 index. On mouse leave it fades out all articles.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I just started jQuery this month so I appreciate the simplified example.

Answer (score 0):

Your hovering is quick before the fade out animation is complete so you are seeing more than two articles when hover.

By default `fadeout()` animation has a duration of 400 ms

I suggest you to use `fadeOut(duration);` property to set the time for animation like

```
fadeOut(1);// or work around the best suited time (in milli secs) for you
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use much simpler code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("h2").hover( 
    function(){
      $("article").finish();
      $("article").eq($(this).index()).fadeIn(300);
    }, 
    function(){
      $("article").hide();
    });
});
```

refer this http://jsbin.com/mavefohobe/1/edit?html,js,console,output